# Ray intersection and child camera

Tags: three.js, camera, intersection, raytracing

I've been playing with three.js for few weeks now and got few inconsistencies on **ray casting**.
Here is a simplified version demonstrating one of the bug I encoutered :

http://jsfiddle.net/eMrhb/12/

The camera is added to the sphere **mesh** for further use of **TrackBallControl** for example.

```
scene.add(mesh);    
mesh.add(camera);
```

Clicking a few times on the sphere and opening the console, show us none of the expected intersections between the **ray** and the **mesh**.

Adding the camera to the scene (http://jsfiddle.net/eMrhb/9/), solves the problem:

```
scene.add(mesh);    
scene.add(camera);
```

But I could use a much more complex hierarchy between my scene objects and the camera to suit my needs.

Is this a limitation? If it is, is there any workarounds I could use?

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting down-voted. This seems like a very good question to me...

Comment: Perhaps it is because you are not adding the camera directly to the scene in the second fiddle, as you claim.

Comment: Excuse my (english) mistake, _directly_ wasn't the right word, I'll fix that.

Comment: Thank you anyway @WestLangley, I was seriously questionning the pertinence of the question myself. That's a relief to hear from you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is fixable.

If the camera is a child of another object that is rotated and or translated, then your have to use a different pattern in ray casting.

Instead of this familiar pattern:

```
var ray = new THREE.Ray( camera.position, vector.subSelf( camera.position ).normalize() );
```

You have to use this pattern instead:

```
var position = camera.matrixWorld.getPosition().clone();
var ray = new THREE.Ray( position, vector.subSelf( position ).normalize() );
```

three.js r.53

Comment: That indeed fixed the problem: <http://jsfiddle.net/eMrhb/13/>. Thank you very much.
In the case of nested objects, will
`camera.matrixWorld.getPosition().clone();`
always do the job or do I need to get through nasty vector multiplications and others matrices updates like other objects?
I read on the wiki that _Camera position and target is updated automatically._ is this only correct for local position?

Comment: I believe this solution will work as is. It is not clear to me what the wiki author meant by the quote you reference. If you have additional problems, please post a new issue.